# How to parsing data selection from JFace Treeviewer to another View in RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

In my application. I have a `Treeviewer` when I select an item on that tree another View will open and I want to parse data from my tree to the new View. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

First, add a selection listener. When selection event occurs, build up the data you want to pass to your view (you may want to cast event.getSeletion() to TreeSelection and iterate over tree paths). In the end, open your view (or you can lookup for a view, if it is already opened and just activate it) and pass your model. It could look something like this:

```
        treeViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
                IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
                Object model = selection.getFirstElement();
                try {
                    YourView view = (YourView) getSite().getPage().showView("your_view_id");
                    view.setModel(model);
                } catch (PartInitException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: I guess it's worth mentioning that setModel is a method that @user3422401 needs to define inside his class, that it's not a ViewPart method

Comment: @VladIlie, thnx for the clarification. I thought it will be clear from the type of opened view=)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When search on google I see something call **Selection Service**. Can I use it in this case? If I can how can I use it?

Comment: You can use it, though to me it seems like a little bit overkill for your case. Selection Service is more generic way to communicate between your workbench parts (like view), but in your case you seem to have pretty straightforward scenario, which could be easily covered with the code I've posted. Here is a good article about the Selection Service: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html